# Can't find my image files while deploying my node js web app on Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, ejs

I have deployed my web app on Heroku, but Heroku's sever can't find my image file located in the static folder.
This is my app.js file....

```
const express=require("express");
const body=require("body-parser");
const http=require("http");
var path = require('path');


const app=express();

var temp="";
var des="";
var city_name="";
var src="";
var cn="";
var temp_max="";
var temp_min="";

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(body.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set("view engine","ejs");

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");
})

app.post("/",(req,res)=>{
    var city=req.body.city;
    var country=req.body.country;
    var date = new Date();
    var api_key="4aa7299408553a0ec003e1dd56d73cf5";
    var url="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=metric&q="+ city +","+country+"&appid=";
    http.get(url+api_key,(response)=>{
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        response.on("data",(data)=>{
            var s=JSON.parse(data);
            temp=s.main.temp;
            city_name=city;
            temp_max=s.main.temp_max;
            temp_min=s.main.temp_min;
            cn=country;
            console.log(s);
            des=s.weather[0].main;
            src=des+".png";
            console.log(src);
            res.redirect("/weather");
            
        })
    })
})

app.get("/weather",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("weather",{temp: temp,city: city_name,des: des,src: src,country: cn,temp_max: temp_max,temp_min: temp_min});
})


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000,()=>{
    console.log("Port 3000");
})
```

My file structure....

```
|--public
  |--images
  |--css
|--views
   |--weather.ejs
 
|--app.js
|--index.html
|--package.json
```

My weather.ejs file--

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Weahter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/weather.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <p><h2><%= city %>, <%= country %></h2></p>
        <p><img src='images/<%= src %>' alts="Des"></p>
        <p><h4><%= temp %>°C</h4></p>
        <p class="temp"><span><%= temp_min %>°C</span>   <span><%= temp_max %>°C</span></p>
        <p><h3><%= des %></h3></p>
        
    </div>
    
        
        
        
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It gives the following error....

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Its works fine on my localserver.
I am very much worried about this problem.
Please help me.

Comment: Did you pushed the image to your git repo or neglected the image folder

Comment: I have pushed everything from the project folder to the git repo.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<p><img src='./public/images/<%= src %>' alts="Des"></p>
```